# list.append() doesn't add any values to the list

Tags: python

I wanted to open a pdb file and extract its sequence but list.append() does not add any object to my list and displays[ ] as output.I tried doing all the possible alternatives but this doesnot work at atall.

```
  file=open("c:/pdb/1ana.pdb")
  for lines in file:
      list1=lines.split()
      id=list1[0]
      list=[]
      if id=='ATOM':
          if list1[2]=='C4':
              list.append(list1[3])
 print(list)
```

Comment: You assign empty list to list by `list=[]` in each iteration. Also it's bad practice to name variables after build-in keywords.

Comment: move `list=[]` outside your `for loop`

Comment: Also, provide your sample input and expect output. That will help us.

Comment: In addition to what others said, you should avoid naming your list `list`, as it will shadow the built-in. Also, consider using an existing PDB parser: http://prody.csb.pitt.edu/tutorials/structure_analysis/pdbfiles.html

Answer (score 5):

`list=[]` is inside for loop which will reset the `list` in each iteration.

Also, avoid using `list` as a variable name because `list` is a keyword in python

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand how the logic of a loop works. Since you have declared an empty list inside a for loop, each time the iterator (lines in your case) iterates over lines, it resets your appended list to an empty list.

So to avoid this, declare your list variable outside of the for loop and append inside your loop.

```
file=open("c:/pdb/1ana.pdb")
list = [] 

for line in file:
list1=lines.split()
    id=list1[0]
    if id=='ATOM':
        if list1[2]=='C4':
            list.append(list1[3])
 print(list)
```

Cheers.